# Can't update latest lollipop patch on rooted Nexus 9

Tags: ota-update, nexus-9

My rooted LTE Nexus 9 running stock 5.1.1 has the Teamwin recovery installed. When I restart to apply the latest lollipop update, I can see error messages in the console as in the pic. Why does it mis identify my device as not having LTE? Is there a way to apply the update without re flashing the stock recovery? Edit - I got the same problem with stock recovery as well.

[image: ![screenshot]]

Comment: Please, what custom rom are you using? You're already running lollipop but just applying latest update or coming from KitKat or so? How are you flashing the update, via pc or recovery?

Comment: No custom ROM, all stock. I have tried the OTA update, rebooting when prompted, but neither stock nor custom recovery are able to install. I got my tablet with 5.1.1 already installed, and rooted it after that.

Comment: Its not like before with kitkat. Google ramped up security for lollipop it now does a full scan of everything. Including checking if the system has ever been mounted r/w. This means no OTA if any part of your system has been modified, corrupted or just weird. Your best bet of you want the OTA is to flash your current lollipop then take the OTA. Honestly that's just busy work because you can just flash the update.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by current lollipop, since I already have the stock unmodified 5.1.1 lollipop with the stock kernel and only changed the recovery. Putting back stock recovery also failed because it's somehow reporting incorrect build.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear your current 5.1.1 build. If your rooted then your system has been modified and has been mounted as r/w = OTA fail. Now the incorrect build is another issue. What does your build prop state.

Comment: It says flounder_lte as it ought. Build id is LMY48I.

Comment: OK, where did you get the twrp download. Because flounder_lte is not officially supported by TWRP. Is it possible you flashed TWRP for flounder? If that is the case when it scans the recovery it will report as flounder not flounder_lte. That's also where the error is happening in your log at cache/recovery/block.map. https://twrp.me/Devices/

Comment: I have removed twrp now, and it's back on stock, but still the same error.

Comment: Twrp was part of the root tool I used.